# How to load next "n" items from the last item i load in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, infinite-scroll

I have data, structured like this:

[image]

I want to load the data from the users as an infite scroll. So I perform a query:

```
mGamersDatabaseReference.child(gameId).orderByChild("gamelvl").limitToFirst(10)
```

Before that I want to load the next 10 items. I already trie using `startAt` and user the userId or the username, but this doesn't load more items.

```
 oldestPlayerGameLvl = myGames.getUserName();
mGamersDatabaseReference.child(gameId).orderByChild("gamelvl").limitToFirst(10).startAt(oldestPlayerGameLvl)
```

This don't load anything and it seems `startAt` method only works if the number, or string starts with the given string or number and not like start from the child or node 5 to the child 10.

**//EDITED**

I use this method and is supposed to load at least the next two items,or im wrong??

```
  mGamersDatabaseReference
  .child(gameId)
  .orderByChild("gamelvl")
  .startAt(0, "-L1Tg7NgZpT_7U4CiAs3") // i use this values
  .limitToFirst(10)
```

in the next is the way is supposed to be,

```
 mGamersDatabaseReference
      .child(gameId)
      .orderByChild("gamelvl")
      .startAt(oldestPlayerGameLvl, oldestPlayerKey) 
      .limitToFirst(10)
```

where oldesPlayerGameLvl equals the value of "gamelvl" in the last node, and 
oldestPlayerKey equals the value of the key in the same last node.
But both methods returns null.

//UPDATE
https://github.com/QaplaGaming/QaplaG/blob/master/qapla.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load the next page of items, you need to know two things:

- The value of `gamelvl` of the last item on the previous page.
- The key of the last item on the previous page, in case there are multiple child nodes with the same value for `gamelvl`.

So if the last item in your screenshot is the last item of the page, you'd get the next page with:

```
mGamersDatabaseReference
  .child(gameId)
  .orderByChild("gamelvl")
  .startAt(0, "-L21rzBM...") // use the entire key
  .limitToFirst(10)
```

Comment: actually, this doesn't work :/ always return null. Looking in firebase documentation to use startAt is like ref.orderByChild("height").startAt(3) and this load the height that starts in 3,like....320,340,etc. And dont seems to work for load at a certain point inside the data. I try use first the key and after the 0(or game lvl) and nothing.

Comment: Update our question to show the minimal code that reproduces what you tried and what it returned. Please read on [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as right now there are some things in your code that we can't know what they are (`mGamersDatabaseReference`, `gameId`, `myGames`). Instead of describing in words what those are, try to reproduce the problem with hard-coded values and share that.

Comment: I dont know, how i can modify to explain :/. I write the same as you. I use the value of the game lvl and the key of the gamelvl. Thats all :/

Comment: I had to use a partial key, you need to provide the entire key: `// use the entire key`. I'm pretty sure I know how the API works, and I'm also pretty sure you're not getting the results you're expecting. Right now something is getting lost in translation. The best way to solve that, is by [providing an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); especially if you reproduce the problem on a site like jsbin, where we can all look at the same thing.

Comment: I edit my question, hope you can understand. And sincerely thanks for your time. :)

Comment: This `.startAt(0, "-L1Tg7NgZpT_7U4CiAs3")` will start at the first player with a `gamelvl` of `0`. If there are multiple players with `gamelvl` equal to `0` it will start at the player with key `-L1Tg7NgZpT_7U4CiAs3`.

Comment: "is supposed" to work this way, but don't work :/ only gives null values i try   **mGamersDatabaseReference.child(gameId).startAt("-L3vWTJKnlmcGMugYih1").limitToLast(10)** but i have the same result

Comment: I can see this warning in the log, i don't know if it affects   `Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "gameExp"' at Gamers/aClash to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance`

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to see where you're going wrong here. Can you set up a jsbin/jsfiddle that reproduces the problem so that we're both looking at the same code+data? Alternatively: update your question to include the actual JSON as text (instead of a screenshot) and I'll set up a jsbin with it. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I add a github, i add my two methods and add 10 users in json formatt. I dont know if this can help, and by the way i have 800 users in the DB :S

Comment: I see two active queries in that code: `orderByChild("gameExp").startAt(oldestIdPlayer)` and `orderByChild("gameExp").limitToFirst(6)`. Both of these are different from my answer, where I pass both the *value of `gamelvl` (`0`) **and** the key of the first matching child in.

Comment: I modify my code but is the same thing, return null, I have comments where I specify that I use the code you say. But you now can see in the github with the changes. But as I say is the same thing. :/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** While my answer was potentially useful for users of Swift or NodeJS, I failed to realize that the Query APIs for the Realtime Database and Firestore aren't well unified across platforms. In particular, you can do things with Queries in NodeJS that you can't do in Swift, and vice-versa. Frank van Puffelen's answer above, I presume, works for Android, where my solution... who knows?

**End edit. The rest is left for posterity.**

This is tricky because there may be many people with the same value for gameLvl. I suggest one of the following solutions:

1. Add a field that somehow combines gameLvl and the user id. For example, it could be a string containing gameLvl (with a fixed number of digits, so 42 could be 00042), followed by a hyphen, followed by the userId. Another example: It could be an integer equal to gameLvl times a billion, plus a hash of the userId modulo a billion. Then order by that field, with your query starting at the last value you retrieved.
2. Switch to Firestore, which is like the real-time database but mostly better. Use `offset` in your query.
3. Switch to Firestore. If the idea of using an offset on a list that might change between your first and second queries makes you squeamish, define an index on game level and userId. Set up your query to be ordered by gameLvl and then userId. Make a query where `gameLvl == lastGameLvl` and `userId > lastUserId`, and if that doesn't get enough results make your next query for `gameLvl > lastGameLvl`.

Comment: As far as I know Firestore also doesn't support offset queries. In fact, the model for pagination is pretty much unchanged between the Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore: both use the concept of an anchor item.

Comment: My mistake -- apparently this is inconsistent between Firestore APIs. nodejs has offset: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/Query#offset

...while Swift has startAtDocument, which is much more useful here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#startatdocument

Comment: I'm actually shocked there is `offset()` anywhere. I wonder how this API works if you insert a document at the front of the collection, while your query is at an offset. It should lead to a lot of index updates in the query snapshot. Wanna give it a try and let us know the result?